# Printing all user created Variables in VisualStudio 2015

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis

I have 8 SSIS packages in a project with different variables. Is there an easy way to print all variables names, scope, DataType, Value, Expression for the whole project?

At this time I am manually typing each variable sheet into excel for audit.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you open to using C# or a .Net language? If so, you can use the SSIS Object Model to iterate over the variables as needed.

All Control Flow Task Hosts inherit from [DtsContainer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtscontainer.aspx). DtsContainer contains a property called Variables, which is a collection of variables in the scope of that container.

So by starting with a Package object, you can get the Package object and all the children (and children of those children, if needed, recursively) as DtsContainer objects. You can get the children of the current object by casting it to [IDTSSequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.idtssequence.aspx) and then accessing the Executables property. Once you have the collection of all the Executables (the package, and children of children) as DtsContainers, you can then access the Variables property of each Container object, over which you can then iterate as you need.

I have uploaded a C# script that does the above here. https://gist.github.com/samskolli/974eaaf9d1bd72fb3ee8bb202e49a058